# M3AKShell.exe exited with error code 9009

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am facing a problem while Re Build my solution. I have added following post build event.

[image]

and now the following error is showing while i am compiling my project.

[image]

I am stuck because of this error and unable to compile my project. Any help will appreciated.

Comment: There's a registry key missing, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7\10.0.  That's pretty unhealthy, are you actually using VS2010?  Re-running install and asking for Repair is the usual next step.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes i am using VS2010 and the registry key is exist which you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of my question. I just ran the following command in cmd and it works.

```
call vsvars32.bat
```

vsvars32.bat file exist in "Visual Studio installation folder"\Common7\Tools. For example in following location in my machine.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
```